# How can I fix the styles for TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, css, themes, tinymce-4

I recently installed TinyMCE (version 4.8.3) into a project I've been working on. Ever since I got it to show up, the styles are not right. They don't look like any theme I've seen on the website.

[image]

I've tried changing the default theme. I've looked to see if our styles are interfering, but all the styles affecting the buttons are prefixed with mce, so I don't think so.

I've searched google, and I have not been able to find anything describing this.

Here is my code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
      selector: "textarea[name=note]",
      themes: "modern",
      theme_url: '/vendors/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js',
      // base: '/vendors/test/tinymce',
      plugins: "lists textcolor link advlist code autoresize amsButtons",
      menubar: "",
      toolbar1: "fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline | bullist numlist link code | amsAtMention amsSubscribe",
    });
```

I've tried many different configurations of the above code.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Have you inspected each of the elements and found out if there are any conflicting styles with the rest of your site? Compare with the demo, or a working version, and find out what additional styles are being displayed (Or lack of), and you'll get an idea of why this is happening.

Comment: I had checked (mentioned above in the question). But, I hadn't checked good enough. I checked again, after your comment, and I found the conflicting styles. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was conflicting styles in our application. I missed them the first time I checked. Problem solved. Thanks!